# Display html chart correctly using two PHP arrays in Laravel

Tags: laravel, charts

I need to display the values based on two arrays as a scatter chart. One of these arrays contains dates in this format "2023/06/06" and the other one contains float numbers. Two arrays have to get the JS file from the Laravel controller method using ->compact() while returning the view. That's how I get the values for the arrays in the controller class:

```
$list = $this->GetDaysList($tableprofitname);
$profitlist = $this->profitlist($tableprofitname);
return view('history', compact('list', 'results', 'profit', 'income_item',
        'income_price', 'income_amount', 'expense_price', 'expense_item', 'expense_amount', 'profitlist'));
```

That's how I convert them into the JS state in the blade file:

```
<script>
        var datearray = {!! json_encode($list) !!};
        var results = {!! json_encode($results) !!};
        var profitlist = {!! json_encode($profitlist) !!};
        if(results == true){
            var profit = {!! json_encode($profit) !!};
            var income_item = {!! json_encode($income_item) !!};
            var income_amount = {!! json_encode($income_amount) !!};
            var income_price = {!! json_encode($income_price) !!};
            var expense_item = {!! json_encode($expense_item) !!};
            var expense_amount = {!! json_encode($expense_amount) !!};
            var expense_price = {!! json_encode($expense_price) !!};
        }
    </script>
```

The JS file:

```
var valuesforchart = [];
for (var i = 0; i < datearray.length; i++) {
valuesforchart.push({ x: datearray[i], y: profitlist[i] });
}

new Chart("myChart", {
type: "scatter",
data: {
    datasets: [
        {
            pointRadius: 4,
            pointBackgroundColor: "red",
            data: valuesforchart,
        },
    ],
},
options: {
    legend: { display: false },
    scales: {
        x: {
            type: "time",
            time: {
                unit: "day", // Display dates by day
            },
        },
    },
},
});
```

And having exclusively one item in each of both arrays I get this result:

[the main issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrzcL.jpg)

It was supposed to see exclusively one value in each axis but I see some absurd. The dates are not visible at all. How can I fix it in order to display the chart and its content normally?

Each of these arrays has only one element. The sample of data:

```
datearray[0] = "2023/06/06";
profitlist[0] = -254672.00;
```

Comment: Nobody knows what is "absurd" or not in your results. Also the PHP/Blade code is likely to be useless here. Does the rendered page contain the correct data? If so this has nothing to do with server-side code.

Comment: Can you please share a sample of the data you pass to the JS code? In the image you show, the Y axis values are not correctly displayed and there are no data points displayed in the chart, these are the issues that you need solved right?

Comment: I have been adding the sample of data. The datearray[0] element was obtained using this command: $profitlist = DB::table($tableprofitname)->pluck('profit'); The field type in the database table is "date".